# I have Galaxy S3 and Kies 2.6 its not backing up SMS messages.. HELP!

Tags: sms, backup

I have Galaxy S3 and I tried to back up all my contents with Kies 2.6... it completed all but my messages (SMS) which is the most important because it contains needed evidence for court. 
How do I figure this out? 
I had tried backing up my current S3 before I attempted using this program on my old S3 which has a shattered screen and cracked digitizer (but other than that everything else still works on it). 
I need to be able to retrieve all SMS messages and screenshots off of the old S3 and all contents from both phones to my computer (which is Windows 10), not just into a folder in the program window.
Please include any possible links.

*UPDATE*: I got the kies 2.6 to backup all the data & files from my broken phone *BUT* the SMS is saved as a .SME file..

*THE PROBLEM WITH THIS* is that now I am having difficulty finding out how to convert these .SME files into a format which is readable by my PC. `

This is because *KIES WON'T ALLOW ME TO OPEN THESE .SME FILES WITH THE PROGRAM ITSELF* also *WON'T ALLOW ME TO TRANSFER THESE SMS- .sme FILES TO MY NEW PHONE*.

I tried downloading an APP to my PC called *"Abylon"* that is suppose to convert .SME files to a different format compatible with PCs etc... However, *THIS PROGRAM IS ABSOLUTE GARBAGE* and does not do diddly. It pops up with error messages and other nonsense which doesn't truly apply... makes me wonder if its just malware.

Comment: Try SMS Backup and Restore by Carbonite: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.riteshsahu.SMSBackupRestore

Comment: I need a program I can install on my PC to retrieve the data from the broken phone. It has a broken digitizer/LCD so I cannot operate/do anything with/on the phone itself. It automatically engages SMP when plugged into the PC using USB data cord and the WiFi was on when the digitizer/LCD both shattered, so i know the WiFi is still on when powered up. After retrieving the data from the broken phone to my PC, I need to transfer it from my PC to my new phone (which is also a Galaxy S3).

Comment: I tried a shareware Abylon something for converting/reading .sme files but its absolute garbage and now have to delete it from my PC.

Comment: I have also looked into "Smart-Switch" which also pretty much worthless because you have to be able to operate the old phone that your transferring the data from.

Comment: Oh I see. Your phone wasn't backed up to google drive or Samsung's servers?

Comment: No, unfortunately not.

Comment: http://forums.androidcentral.com/samsung-galaxy-s3/275322-how-transfer-files-galaxy-s3-broken-screen.html